# Sequence calculation issues

Tags: python, numbers

I've tried to calculate the maximum length of even digits in a number, and print the index that the sequence starts with and the sequence itself.

Here is the code I've started with, but it has some bugs:

```
num = int(eval(input("Please enter a positive integer: ")))

length=0
seq=None
start = -1
while num!=0:
     d = num % 2
     num = num /10
     if d==0:
        length=length+1


print("The maximal length is", length)
print("Sequence starts at", start)
print("Sequence is", seq)}
```

Comment: What are the bugs? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you see a `NameError` exception (but I shouldn't have to: when you report issues with your code it is important to report its behavior as well, don't just say "it doesn't work" because there are a million ways it could fail). [Note: I suspect this is only because the code was mangled by the formatting system, so I assume you do actually read a number into `num`].

Is is acceptable to find the run only at the beginning? What about 345666678? You currently have nothing in your code that will move the start point forward. But your code shows many of the right ideas, so let's discuss what the algorithm's strategy should be.

Since there's the possibility that there may be many runs in the number, the task reduces to finding all runs and selecting the longest. So start by setting `longest_run` to zero, where it should stay if the number contains only odd digits.

When you find an odd digit (*and* at the end of the string), compare the current `run_length` with the `longest_run` and replace it if longer (this must be the end of a run, even if a run of length zero) then set the run_length back to zero. When you find an even digit, add one to the `run_length`.

You appear to be a beginner, so congratulations on getting so many elements of the problem correct.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be the following:

```
a = int(eval(input("Please enter a positive integer: ")))
# Items in the sequence to look for
even = ['0','2','4','6','8']
# Length of the current sequence
le = 0
# and starting position
st = -1
# Length of the longest sequence
maxLe = 0
# and starting position
maxSt = -1

# Loop through the digits of the number
for idx,num in enumerate(str(a)):
    if num in even:
        le += 1
        if le == 1:
            # If it is a new sequence, save the starting position
            st = idx
    else:
        # If there are no more even digits, check if it is the longest sequence
        if le > maxLe:
            maxLe = le
            maxSt = st
        # Reset to look for the next sequence
        le = 0
```

Comment: I didn't understand this part:
for idx,num in enumerate(str(a)):
what does idx and enumerate mean?

Comment: If you use "enumerate" in the loop you receive two values: the "index" (or position inside the array) and the "value", which is what you typically use in the loops.

Comment: In any case, if this code worked, please select my answer and marked the question as "answered". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x version (it was unclear which one you want):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

even = '02468' # even = ''.join(range(0,10,2))

# in python 2.x is very unsafe and unreliable, use raw_input
answer = raw_input('Please enter a positive integer: ')
# in python 3.x you can use input(), but just cast it to desired
# type and catch errors with 'except ValueError:' clause or...

# check here if all characters are digits:
if not answer.strip().isdigit():
    print ("Wrong input.")
    sys.exit(1)

sequence = answer

# this returns number of consecutive even digits
def even_len(sequence):
    for i, digit in enumerate(sequence):
        if digit not in even:
            return i # early break on the first odd digit
    return i

start, length = 0, 0
i, n = 0, len(sequence)
while i < n:
    this_len = even_len(sequence[i:]) # search for rest of input
    if this_len > length:
        length = this_len
        start = i
    i += this_len + 1 # let's skip already checked digits

print("The maximal length is", length)
print("Sequence starts at", start)
print("Sequence is", sequence[start : start+length])
```